# How to call Wax action in PHP

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs

All of the tutorials on building dApps, they use Javascript and then they tell you how NOT to do it by using your PK to create a signature.

So I'd like to use PHP on the backend and grab my key from a db or something... is there a framework that lets me call wax/eos actions from within PHP?

Comment: hello Todd, you may get a faster answer here: https://t.me/waxdevelopers

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any PHP libraries that can let you interact with an eosio-based blockchain.

You can try to post your question on this eosio devs telegram channel: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Another idea is to use eosjs from within your php code.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with PHP is very limited but I'd assume you could install [cleos](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/cleos/index) or [eosc](https://github.com/eoscanada/eosc) and call the functions you need via `exec(...);` like

```
exec("cleos wallet unlock $wallet_pw", $output);

exec("cleos push transaction $transaction_json", $output);
```

and so on.